# How do I make my app appear in the "open in" dialog in Apple Mail for jpeg and png files?

Tags: ios, png, jpeg

I am developing a program that imports files from email. I can import most extensions by properly writing UTIs into my p-info lists, but I cannot find workable information on how to make my app appear in the "open in" dialog in the Apple Mail app for jpeg and png files. Also, although .pages files can be imported from email, my app does not appear in an "open in" or "share" dialog in the Pages app.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

A similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736812/how-to-register-the-app-to-open-the-jpeg-png-and-gif-image-file-in-my-app-in-i was asked last year but not answered.